# Can Not Start Glassfish 4.1 Server, Download, Unzip, Install, Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, command-line, java, zip, glassfish

Before I start I wanted to say, I have to put a space in many of the links because I am new to superuser & have restrictions.  You'll find the spaces http:// (HERE) localhost:4848/. I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I hope this restriction will be lifted soon.

I can not start, Glassfish 4.1 server.
I'm running, *Windows 8.1, 64x.*

I downloaded, *Java EE 7 Full Platform glassfish-4.1.zip*
**From here:** https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Unzipped with, *7-Zip 9.20*. Put zipped in a folder with my other zipped.
Put unzipped in *C*.

**Path:** *C:\glassfish-4.1*
Next inside, *glassfish4*.

**Path:** *C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish4*
[image: pic]

Next inside, *bin*.

**Path:** *C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish4\bin*
[image]

Now in, *asadmin Windows Batch File*, opens Command prompt, *C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, asadmin>*.

Enter, *start-domain*, Then cmd.exe outputs *Waiting for domain1 to start........(lots of these)......serverNoStart
Command start-domain failded.*

Opened, *pkg*, ran it, it installed.
[image]

Opened, *updatetools* ran it, it installed.
[image]

Again, in *asadmin Windows Batch File*, opens Command prompt, *C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, asadmin>.*

Enter, *start-domain*, Then cmd.exe outputs *Waiting for domain1 to start........(lots of these)......serverNoStart
Command start-domain failded.*

If I try *asadmin start-domain* or *glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain* from this location I get the following.
[image]

I'd like to better understand the nature of this problem. Suggestions on how to fix/start server?

P.S. when I check http://localhost:4848/
[image]

P.S.S. when I try to start GlassFish from Netbeans...

[image]

Comment: I have submitted an edit to be reviewed. If you think I removed too much, you may reject or rollback my edit. For some reason, I cannot get your screen shots to work right.

Comment: I think you did a great job.  Any ideas of how to deal with GlassFish?

Comment: please upload the server log. If there is too much to paste here, use something like pastebin. Your server log should be here: `C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs/server.log` it should contain any errors it encountered while trying to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last screenshot where you try to start GlassFish through Netbeans suggests that there is already something running which is bound to port 8080 and/or port 8443. Check if there's no other application server (Tomcat etc) currently running.

Aside from that, your server log should tell you what is going wrong:

```
C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike. In my case, Tomacat is running at 8080 so I was getting "Waiting for domain1 to start ........." in Terminal (Mac OS X Yosemite) then I changed the port number from 8080 to 9090 in /glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml. Now, glassfish server is running successfully.

Answer (score 6):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317527/how-do-i-clear-an-address-for-glassfish-4-0-with-default-settings

The main reason is that another server is using the port 8080, that is the one per default (to check in windows if those ports are being used in the commands line: `netstat -a -o`)

You would need to change it in:

`/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`

```
Change: name="http-listener-1" port="8080"
        name="http-listener-2" port="8181"

To:     name="http-listener-1" port="9090"
        name="http-listener-2" port="9191"
```

Then, remove the server from your framework (Eclipse for example), close it, start it and add the Glashfish again.

Before starting your framework make sure there is no file such:

```
/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/felix/*.lock
```

In case it exists, remove it, you may stop any Java process for removing it.

These steps worked for me.